# Assigning weights in stat evaluation of NFL quarterbacks

Tags: percentage, variability

I'm doing a statistical analysis of multiple former and current NFL quarterbacks to try to determine who is the best ever. Basically, I'm doing this by evaluating how much better or worse than a season's league average a player was in total yards, completion percentage, yards per attempt and TD:Int ratio. I find a player's percentage increase or decrease from a season's league average for a given statistic and add up those deviations for four different categories: regular season, five-year peak, postseason and Super Bowl.

Anyway, the issue I'm running into is that of high variability, particularly with TD:Int ratio. I've evaluated Troy Aikman and Terry Bradshaw, and TD:Int ratio made up 67% of both of their subtotals. Most league average ratios are around 1, and it's not terribly difficult for an above average QB to have a 2:1 ratio. I'm trying to bring down the splits so that, generally speaking, total yards, completion percentage, yards per attempt and TD:Int ratio are all around 25% of the subtotals.

Thoughts on how to do that, and thoughts on my research in general? Thank you!

Comment: Regarding: "I'm trying to bring down the splits so that, generally speaking, total yards, completion percentage, yards per attempt and TD:Int ratio are all around 25% of the subtotals." Isn't this a matter of simply normalizing the variables to be on the same scale? You can apply standard techniques, such as subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, as found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score